# Getting Nan Values from Overlap Analysis Tool

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to run the Overlap Analysis Tool to get the overlapping area of a shapefile for each box in a grid. Here's an example portion of my data where I am using the blue layer as the input layer and the orange-red layer as the overlay layer.
[image]

I receive no errors in the output log, but when checking the attribute table, the values are either 0 or nan as pictured below.
[image]

Any idea on what might be the issue? I'm also happy hear about any other methods to try instead of the Overlap Analysis tool if the problem might be inherent to a feature of the tool.

For additional context:
I've been following the steps in this video here (i.e. Collecting the geometry and fixing the geometries before running the overlap analysis tool). I've checked, and the projections are indeed the same for both layers (a Tranverse Mercator Moon projection).